# SKShapeNode: Shader transparency is ignored

Tags: swift, opengl, sprite-kit, shader, skshapenode

I want to fill a `SKShapeNode` with a linear gradient. Being a programming perfectionist I want the solution to be as customizable as possible. So I decided to use a [`fillShader`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshapenode/1519629-fillshader/). Here's the shader:

```
let shader = SKShader(
    source: "void main() {" +
    "vec4 c1 = vec4(1, 1, 1, 0.25);" +
    "vec4 c2 = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);" +
    "vec2 p1 = vec2(0, 0);" +
    "vec2 p2 = vec2(1, 1);" +
    "vec2 v0 = p2 - p1;" +
    "vec2 v = v_tex_coord - p1;" +
    "float t = dot(v, v0) / (length(v0) * length(v0));" +
    "t = clamp(t, 0.0, 1.0);" +
    "gl_FragColor = mix(c1, c2, t);" +
    "}")
```

*(`c1`, `c2`, `p1`, `p2` should be attributes but here they are constant to isolate the bug)*

**So the problem is the shader ignores alpha**, and instead of transparent color white I see solid white in the corner:

[image: Gradient]

If you change `c1` and `c2` to other colors, the bug will stay there.

Comment: You have to enable [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending)

Comment: The result from the shader needs to be in premultiplied alpha form, but `c1` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comments said, the color value you return should already be premultiplied by the fragment's alpha value.

From [Apple's documentation - Creating a Custom Fragment Shader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshader/creating_a_custom_fragment_shader):

> Typically, the color value you return in this variable should already be premultiplied by the fragment’s alpha value.

You might also want to use `v_color_mix.a` if you want your shader to take into account the alpha value set on the node:

`gl_FragColor = col * v_color_mix.a;`

Comment: `v_color_mix` didn't work for me (`fillColor` is unused and set to `nil`) but premultiplation worked, thanks!